# for nested loop with if

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, dictionary

I am trying to parse string which have keys in dictionary vs which don't have. Below is the code. It works perfectly fine with the matching ones' but when it writes string for which there is no key in dictionary, it writes duplicate. I am trying to write just once after making sure that string has no keys in dictionary.

I couldn't figure out the way to get out from the loop.

```
    import csv
# Create Dictionary structure of csv file 2
with open("dict.csv", "rb") as fp:
    dic_file = csv.reader(fp,)
    dict1 = {}
    for d in dic_file:
        dict1[d[1]] = d[0]

print dict1

with open("match_out.csv", "wb") as fw1:
    with open("file.csv", "r") as fr1:
        with open("nomatch_out.csv", "wb") as fw2:
            output = csv.writer(fw1, delimiter=",")
            writer1 = csv.writer(fw2,delimiter=",")
            read = csv.reader(fr1,)     
            for row in read:
                for d in dict1:
                    if d == row[2]:
                        output.writerow(row) ## write only the matching ones

                    else:
                        writer1.writerow(row) ## if no key/match write to a separate file
```

Comment: can you post an example of your current result and the one you are expecting ? it's hard to figure out the problem with all those loops... cheers

Comment: @Vtik my current output gives me matched records on match_out.csv file but I get everything in nomatch_out.csv. Since, I have five key_value pair in dictionary it gives me five duplicate instances for each row of 'file.csv' in nomatch_csv instead of one instance of the row which doesn't have key in dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy work around would be testing for a temporary Boolean (found_) as the following :

```
import csv
# Create Dictionary structure of csv file 2
with open("dict.csv", "rb") as fp:
    dic_file = csv.reader(fp,)
    dict1 = {}
    for d in dic_file:
        dict1[d[1]] = d[0]

print dict1
found_ = None #not necessary

with open("match_out.csv", "wb") as fw1:
    with open("file.csv", "r") as fr1:
        with open("nomatch_out.csv", "wb") as fw2:
            output = csv.writer(fw1, delimiter=",")
            writer1 = csv.writer(fw2,delimiter=",")
            read = csv.reader(fr1,)     
            for row in read:
                found_ = False
                for d in dict1:
                    if d == row[2]:
                        found_ = True
                if found_:    
                    output.writerow(row) ## write only the matching ones
                else: 
                    writer1.writerow(row) ## if no key/match write to a separate file
```